# Statics Banner Content Consider as Duplicate?

Tags: duplicate-content, content, banners

One Quarry!!

Suppose if I have site having 10 pages (with 3 different categories) and all pages have one static banner which is running in all pages. Now let say it 3 categories be A, B , C defining 3 services and having few content on the banner representing the service then condition of duplicate content will arise or not??

Comment: This definitely will not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Not at all a duplicate content.. Don't bother about it.. If your banner is an image then it will not be consider for content count. Search Engine will never consider this as duplicate content. For more information related to duplicate content read this

[What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: Sathiya what will happen in case if banner is not and image and its content is cached then?

Comment: You said that banner is representing the service, so it's not a content spam. I think you can't represent your service in multiple ways on multiple pages. If you are using full content of a particular page on multiple pages of your website then it will be a content spam and you have to use canonical tag, but in your case, using canonical tag is not possible. Even Google easily differentiate the spam content and good content. You don't worry Justice :)

Comment: Matt Cutts mentioned in his latest update about Duplicate content. He says Duplicate Content won't hurt you unless it is spammy. See this post http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-duplicate-content-wont-hurt-you-unless-it-is-spammy-167459